# Ng-if With Dynamic href and conditional

Tags: angularjs

I have to set href dynamic on conditional basis.

My code is :

```
<a class="venobox" ng-href="{{x.PortfolioImagejpg=='' ? '' :
 'upload/ProductImage/{{x.PortfolioImagejpg}}'}}" data-
gall="myGallery">View</a>
```

But "{{" will not work properly.

If i am doing

```
<a class="venobox" ng-href="{{x.PortfolioImagejpg=='' ? '' : 
'upload/ProductImage/x.PortfolioImagejpg'}}" data-
gall="myGallery">View</a>
```

Then this will be work but i need dynamic image name binding.

Could you please suggest a way of how to implement such a functionality in Angular?

Comment: try 'upload/ProductImage/'+x.PortfolioImagejpg

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: is x.PortfolioImagejpg defined? Can you make a plunker?

Comment: This - `ng-href="{{x.PortfolioImagejpg === '' ? '' : 'upload/ProductImage/' + x.PortfolioImagejpg}}"` - does work ([plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1EOBJJlA8PJpMTXBCuIm?p=preview)). It might be unexpected, but yes, empty `ng-href` essentially turns off a _link_ (making `<a>` an anchor - linkable - element). No need to wrap parts of this expression in parentheses, they only complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

you have curly braces within curly braces, thus inner expression is not evaluated:

```
ng-href="{{x.PortfolioImagejpg=='' ? '' : 'upload/ProductImage/{{x.PortfolioImagejpg}}'}}"
```

use only one pair of braces:

```
ng-href="{{ x.PortfolioImagejpg ? '' : 'upload/ProductImage/' + x.PortfolioImagejpg }}"
```

but better would be this:

```
<a class="venobox" 
   ng-if="x.PortfolioImagejpg" 
   data-gall="myGallery"
   ng-href="upload/ProductImage/{{ x.PortfolioImagejpg }}">
  View
</a>
```

if there is nothing to view, then the link will be not rendered at all